# ASP.NET MVC. Is it possible to use MVC Foolproof Validation for array validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, foolproof-validation

E.g. I have the following model:

```
public class MyModel {
public Line[] Lines{get;set;}
}

public class Line {
public int Quantity{get;set;}
public int MaxQuantity{get;set;}
}
```

The "Quantity" field should be less than "MaxQuantity" so I tried to use "LessThanOrEqualTo" validation attribute:

```
public class Line {
[LessThanOrEqualTo("MaxQuantity")]
public int Quantity{get;set;}
public int MaxQuantity{get;set;}
}
```

But it does not work on client side because of wrong dependent property name I believe:

```
<input type="number" value="1" name="Lines[0].Quantity" data-val-is-passonnull="False" data-val-is-operator="LessThanOrEqualTo" data-val-is-dependentproperty="MaxQuantity" data-val-is="Quantity must be less than or equal to MaxQuantity." data-val="true">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="Lines[0].MaxQuantity">
```

You can see that "`data-val-is-dependentproperty="MaxQuantity"`" but real input name is "`Lines[0].MaxQuantity"`"

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: are you using html helpers to render those input tags?

Comment: @Cris: yes, I use html helpers

Answer (score 0):

Have you included mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js in your view or your master page? 
Have you checked that the script is loaded before your code is using it?

With my Foolproof Nuget installation, it was placed in "Client Scripts" folder from Foolproof Nuget installation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I was tracking down an issue I was having using foolproof in arrays so I got a little deeper into its inner workings.

It's ok that the data-val-is-dependentproperty name simply says "MaxQuantity". Foolproof uses a method in its client script called getId() to get the id of the dependent element by parsing the id of the compare element.

```
foolproof.getId = function (element, dependentPropety) {
    var pos = element.id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1;
    return element.id.substr(0, pos) + dependentPropety.replace(/\./g, "_");
};
```

The underlying problem is that your rendered HTML elements have name attributes, but don't have id attributes.

My issue turned out to be that the foolproof regex for dates doesn't recognize the `yyyy-MM-dd` format as a date. Normally it wouldn't be a problem since it's a sortable format, but it was trying to compare to a date in a hidden field which was in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss` because HiddenFor doesn't obey DisplayFormat.ApplyFormatInEditMode.